# SortedSet map does not always preserve element ordering in result?

Tags: scala

Given the following Scala 2.9.2 code:

**Updated with non-working example**

```
import collection.immutable.SortedSet

case class Bar(s: String)

trait Foo {
  val stuff: SortedSet[String]
  def makeBars(bs: Map[String, String])
    = stuff.map(k => Bar(bs.getOrElse(k, "-"))).toList
}

case class Bazz(rawStuff: List[String]) extends Foo {
  val stuff = SortedSet(rawStuff: _*)
}


// test it out....
val b = Bazz(List("A","B","C"))
b.makeBars(Map("A"->"1","B"->"2","C"->"3"))
// List[Bar] = List(Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(3))
// Looks good?

// Make a really big list not in order. This is why we pass it to a SortedSet...    
val data =  Stream.continually(util.Random.shuffle(List("A","B","C","D","E","F"))).take(100).toList
val b2 = Bazz(data.flatten)

// And how about a sparse map...?
val bs = util.Random.shuffle(Map("A" -> "1", "B" -> "2", "E" -> "5").toList).toMap
b2.makeBars(bs)
// res24: List[Bar] = List(Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(-), Bar(5))
```

I've discovered that, in some cases, the `makeBars` method of classes extending `Foo` does *not* return a sorted List. In fact, the list ordering does *not* reflect the ordering of the `SortedSet`

What am I missing about the above code where Scala will not always map a `SortedSet` to a `List` with elements ordered by the `SortedSet` ordering?

Comment: You need to present an actually not working example.

Comment: Agreed. That will take some time as I'll have to sanitize some proprietary code.

Comment: Updated. I left out that he map function is actually wrapping the elements of the `stuff` SortedSet in a case class "Bar"

Comment: Updated again, this time demonstrating yet more defects in the `makeBars` function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're being surprised by implicit resolution.

The `map` method requires a `CanBuildFrom` instance that's compatible with the target collection type (in simple cases, identical to the source collection type) and the mapper function's return type.

In the particular case of `SortedSet`, its implicit `CanBuildFrom` requires that an `Ordering[A]` (where A is the return type of the mapper function) be available.  When your map function returns something that the compiler already knows how to find an `Ordering` for, you're good:

```
scala> val ss = collection.immutable.SortedSet(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
ss: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
                                                        6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val result1 = ss.map(_ * 2)
result1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
                                                            12, 14, 16, 18, 20) 
                 // still sorted because Ordering[Int] is readily available

scala> val result2 = ss.map(_ + " is a number")
result2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[String] = TreeSet(1 is a number, 
                                                                10 is a number, 
                                                                2 is a number, 
                                                                3 is a number, 
                                                                4 is a number, 
                                                                5 is a number, 
                                                                6 is a number, 
                                                                7 is a number, 
                                                                8 is a number, 
                                                                9 is a number) 
// The default Ordering[String] is an "asciibetical" sort, 
// so 10 comes between 1 and 2. :)
```

However, when your mapper function turns out to return a type for which no Ordering is known, the implicit on `SortedSet` doesn't match (specifically, no value can be found for its implicit parameter), so the compiler looks "upward" for a compatible `CanBuildFrom` and finds the generic one from `Set`.

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val result3 = ss.map(Foo(_))
result3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Foo] = Set(Foo(10), Foo(4), Foo(6), Foo(7), Foo(1), Foo(3), Foo(5), Foo(8), Foo(9), Foo(2))

// The default Set is a hash set, therefore ordering is not preserved
```

Of course, you can get around this by simply supplying an instance of `Ordering[Foo]` that does whatever you expect:

```
scala> implicit val fooIsOrdered: Ordering[Foo] = Ordering.by(_.i)
fooIsOrdered: Ordering[Foo] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@7512dbf2

scala> val result4 = ss.map(Foo(_))
result4: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Foo] = TreeSet(Foo(1), Foo(2), 
                                                       Foo(3), Foo(4), Foo(5), 
                                                       Foo(6), Foo(7), Foo(8), 
                                                       Foo(9), Foo(10))
  // And we're back!
```

Finally, note that toy examples often don't exhibit the problem, because the Scala collection library has special implementations for small (n <= 6) Sets and Maps.

Comment: OP would have picked up his error (of not defining an Ordering for Bar) if he'd supplied a type annotation for his `makeBars` method.

Comment: @Alex Cruise Wow, that's absolutely fantastic! Yet one more reason why I don't always like the inheritance structure of Scala collections.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably making assumption about what SortedSet does from Java.  You need to specify what order you want the elements to be in.  See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_8.html

Comment: Actually, I made a bad assumption about `map`, because I have been so used to Clojure where the map function always returns a `seq` - there is no `CanBuildFrom`.