# Order of elements shown in generated HTML doesn't match the order of the elements in the collection

Tags: scala, collections, playframework, playframework-2.3, twirl

I'm getting crazy in struggling to understand why is this happening: I have a collection (a immutable SortedSet) containing 6 integers, and I iterate on them via `.map` method to create my generated HTML. The elements in the HTML page always show in different order every time I reload the page.

Here's some excerpts from my template

```
@deltas = @{ scala.collection.SortedSet[Int]( -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15) }

     @*** More code here ***@

@Logger.debug("DELTAS="+deltas.toString())
@deltas.map { delta =>
<li>
  @Logger.debug("DELTA="+delta.toString())
  <a href="#">@{dist.toDouble.intValue + delta}&nbsp;km (@delta)</a>
</li>
}
```

I also tried to Log the output to the screen - see Logger - and as expected the elements are always shown in the correct order.

```
[debug] application - DELTAS=TreeSet(-15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15)
[debug] application - DELTA=-15
[debug] application - DELTA=-10
[debug] application - DELTA=-5
[debug] application - DELTA=5
[debug] application - DELTA=10
[debug] application - DELTA=15
```

Now I can only say the issue must be in the template engine, but I'd like to know whether it is a bug (unlikely) or I just need to know something more about some tricky aspect of it (very likely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it seems it has something to do with a template engine. I need to dig down more to find out a reason. At this moment I can suggest a solution to this problem by using collection's iterator.

```
@for(delta <- deltas.iterator) {
<li>
  <a href="#">@{dist.toDouble.intValue + delta}&nbsp;km (@delta)</a>
</li>
}
```

You can also convert TreeSet to Seq which solves the problem too.

**Previous**

First clue before update:

You can read this question to learn more about a SortedSet mapping

[SortedSet map does not always preserve element ordering in result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528357/sortedset-map-does-not-always-preserve-element-ordering-in-result)

Comment: I've read the post you pointed out, but it has nothing to do with what I got in my code: if you take a  closer look to the code I posted and to the Logger output, you'll be agreeing with me that the same iteration gives a correct result on the terminal (Logger) where Play is running but on the generated HTML page, I have a random order every time I load the page (this is one more evidence it has nothing to do with your suggestion).

Comment: The iterator method solved the problem! I tried other iteration techniques before your suggestion, with no luck...